# Universal links from Flutter app don't open wanted screen if app is terminated/killed

Tags: flutter, ios-universal-links

I have a problem with universal link in my iOS app made with Flutter. 
I have successfully setup everything and link for resetting password in my app is working fine. On my Android app I have no problems, but on my iOS app it doesn't work properly if the app is terminated, it opens the app, but does not navigate to the reset password screen, instead it navigates me to the **initial route** of the app, which is splash screen.

Here is the code from my gorouter:

```
GoRoute(name: RoutesName.resetPassword,
        path: RoutesName.resetPassword,
        builder: (context, state) {
            final email = state.uri.queryParameters['email'];
            final token = state.uri.queryParameters['token'];
            return ResetPasswordView(token, email);
        })
```

RoutesName.resetPassword is the same as the route from my url, so: **"/reset-password"**
If you have any idea on how to solve this, please respond.